# Eval SQL in Org Babel using sql-connection-alist for credentials

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel, sql-mode

I would like to evaluate SQL source blocks in Org Babel using the connections I have set up in `sql-connection-alist` from `sql-mode`. This way I can save database credentials in a private (Elisp) file and share the files with the queries.

Is there any way to configure this in Org Mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I submitted a patch to do this: [ob-sql.el: Option to reference connections in `sql-connection-alist'](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2019-03/msg00277.html). It should be included in the next version of Org Mode.

Comment: It's out with Org 9.3

Comment: Last time I tried using this I was looking for exactly this and gave up, glad to see it has been added. Super useful - thanks!